# Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php, sql-server

Tengo un formulario que ingresa personas , pero tengo problemas para validar usando  `sqlsrv_num_rows()` el error es el siguente:

> Warning: sqlsrv_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";
function ingresar(){

$con=conectar();

$nom=$_POST['nombre'];
$rut=$_POST['rut'];
$tel=$_POST['telefono'];
$dir=$_POST['direccion'];

    $sql="select RutAux From cwtauxi where RutAux=$rut";
    $stmt=sqlsrv_query($con,$sql);

    error-> if(sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt)>0){
        ?>
                  <div class="alert-false" role="alert">El Registro ya existe</div><?php
                        sqlsrv_close($con); 

    }else{

          $sql2="insert into cwtauxi (NomAux,RutAux,DirAux,FonAux1)values ('$nom','$rut','$dir','$tel')";
          $stmt2= sqlsrv_query($con, $sql2);
          if($stmt2){

              ?><div class="alert-true" role="alert">Datos ingresados</div><?php
                            sqlsrv_close($con);

          }else{        
                  ?>
                  <div class="alert-false" role="alert">ERROR: <?php  print_r( sqlsrv_errors())?> </div><?php
                                sqlsrv_close($con);

          }         
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: ¿La columna `RutAux` es numérica? Si no es así debes rodear la variable de comillas simples. Verifica también si la conexión es válida. Y más adelante considera blindar tu código contra ataques de inyección SQL.

Comment: Intenta usando `print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true);` para ver la salida del error

Comment: Efectivamente RutAux es un dato varchar agregue las comillas simple pero esta vez use sqlsrv_has_row
    
    sql="select RutAux From cwtauxi where RutAux='$rut'";
  $stmt=sqlsrv_query($con,$sql);

  if(sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt)){
   ?>
       <div class="alert-false" role="alert">El Registro ya existe</div><?php
         sqlsrv_close($con); 

  }

Comment: Pero no dices si se resolvió o si sigue dando error y que error da en ese caso...

Comment: Quedo solucionado